# Looking for function to dominate $\Phi_\varepsilon = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x/\varepsilon)^2}{2}}}{\varepsilon}$.

Tags: limits, fourier-analysis, exponential-function

whilst trying to prove the fourier inversion formula I have to apply the dominated convergence theorem to swap limit and integral, however the function I have to dominate is:
$\Phi_\varepsilon = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x/\varepsilon)^2}{2}}}{\varepsilon}$ as $\varepsilon$ goes to zero. 
I have tried to find something, but nothing seems to work, especially since the function has to be $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. If anyone has a clue I would appreciate all the help I can get. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In the sense of distributions, this converges to a Dirac delta, so it cannot be dominated by any $L^1$ function ...

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should've checked that... If DCT fails here, do you have an idea hoe else I could prove the statement? We haven't yet introduced the Dirac delta function so I only know of it via the physisists I had spoken with...

Comment: Please show your proof and the step that is problematic if you want more precise help

Comment: $(\Phi_\epsilon)$ is an approximate identity. It might be instructive to ctrl+F the keyword "approximate identity" in the textbooks.

Comment: The aim of my proof was to show that: $||\int_{\mathbb{R}} (f(x-t) - f(x)) 1/\varepsilon \Phi (t / \varepsion)} dt ||_{L^1} \rightarrow 0}$ as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ I used the minkowski inequality to pull the $L^1$ norm into the integral, then pulled $\Phi$ out of the nom, since it isn't dependant on x. As It was given, that $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, I concluded that I can just rewrite the $L^1$ norm as a $L^1$ function dependant on t. I then used DCT (even though now I know it doesn't work here) to swap limit and integeal, as the Phi/epsiplon part converges ptw. to 0, I said it conv to 0

Comment: @OnurOktay, thanks I will have a look later today :)